# fancyvrb, helvetica and underscore... is it just me?

Tags: fonts, verbatim, fancyvrb

Ran into some weirdness with `fancyvrb`, `helvetica` and `_`. Here's a MWE (for me):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[fontfamily=helvetica]
Oh no! It's a `_'. `\_' not much better.
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Without any warnings or apologies, it produces

[image]

...i.e., missing a couple of underscores. Strange thing is, it works fine for `fontfamily=courier`.

Anyone come across anything like this before?

I'm not commited to `fancyvrb` so if a work-around is awkward, would happily take suggestions for another helvetica/sans-serif verbatim environment which would handle underscores.

Comment: For posterity, I've just realised that this problem is not specific to `fancyvrb`, but rather of `\sffamily` (even in plain text). No biggie though: see Gonzalo's solution below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the Cork encoding:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

The following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[fontfamily=helvetica]
Oh no! It's a `_'. `\_' not much better.
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

produces the expected result:

[image]

Comment: Cheers! Works like a charm.